# Trying to check if photo link returns 404 with ajax. Status always returning 0

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to check if a photo link is returning a 404 or not.

I'm developing on `localhost:xxxx`, so I'm guessing this is a cross-origin issue.

I was originally getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:xxxx' is therefore not allowed access`.  I looked into that and installed this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en), which disables cross-origin resource sharing.

However after installing the extension, I am no longer getting the above error, but checking the `status` of the request always results in `0`.

How should I go about solving this problem?

```
photo = 'http://example.com/apple.jpg';

var photoCheck = new XMLHttpRequest();
photoCheck.open('HEAD', photo, true);
photoCheck.send();
console.log(photoCheck.status); // Always returns 0
```

Comment: `so I'm guessing this is a cross-origin issue` - exactly, with a CORS request that has no CORS response headers, status will always be 0

Comment: Get rid of that extension, it's opening up your browser to a world of hurt. CORS isn't just protecting resources from people "stealing" them, it also protects you against malicious websites. Learn to deal with CORS issues. If you wrote the server, add cors headers, if not, use your own server to "proxy" your requests to the third party server

Comment: @JaromandaX How is the request still CORS, if the header is disabled?

Comment: no, the header is not disabled at all - read what the extension does ***`Adds to response 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header`*** - that's ENabled

Comment: @JaromandaX Understood.  I'm still a bit confused though, is this a cross-origin issue, or is it another issue?

Comment: it's the fact that xmlhttprequest is asynchronous, and you are checking status in the "wrong place" - you need to check in the `.onload` handler - BUT, if you do have CORS issues, then you'll also get status of zero always, though, not sure if onload would be called in that case

Comment: @Valachio it's both. You won't be able to make any requests from JavaScript to a resource on another origin unless the remote resource supports CORS (or you disable your browser's single-origin policy). And then, you need to wait for the request to complete before being able to properly read the status.

Comment: You could always just create an `<img>` element and add `onload` and `onerror` handlers to detect if its `src` property loads correctly

Comment: @Phil Would I need to worry about cross-origin issues with the `<img>` method?

Comment: @Valachio nope :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I'd go about this a different way.

If you're looking at an online image, you can simply use an `<img>` element. This is allowed to be loaded from any domain (unless you try and bring in an `http` resource into an `https` page).

I'd try something like this...

```
function photoCheck(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    img.onload = resolve
    img.onerror = reject
    img.src = url
  })
}
```

Then you can easily use

```
photoCheck('http://example.com/apple.jpg').then(() => {
  console.info('Image loads ok')
}, e => {
  console.warn('Image failed to load', e)
})
```

Comment: This is a better answer for my particular situation since I don't want to worry about cross-origin issues.  With `fetch()`, I have to send a CORS request which will require me to do additional things on the backend when I go into production.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what if I'm using a div `background-image`?  Since there is no built in `onload` and `onerror` functions, this method only works for `<img>` right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the request to complete. The status will be 0 while the request is in progress. I would highly recommend using fetch which supports promises and generally makes requests easier

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

```
fetch('http://example.com/apple.jpg')
  .then(res => console.log(res.status))
```

Comment: or, check the status in a callback https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue.  If I set the synchronous issue to `false`, it still returns 0

Comment: EDIT - Sorry my mistake.  You are right.  I was checking the wrong thing.  Setting synchronous to `false` does return the right code.